# Smart Contract with Mint and Payable Function (ERC20)

Tags: solidity, remix

I would like to create smart contract where You can mint new tokens (accesible by anyone calling) and charge a fee during that mint payable to contract creator. Something like a donation, but with the mint new tokens function at the same time.

I came up with something like this (changed onlyOwner to paybale), but how to set I believe msg.value to call a specific amount to pay during the mint. I would appreciate every answer as Im struggling with that for hours now .. thank You.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public payble {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    address public creatorAddress = 0xYOUR_ADDRESS;

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public payable {
        _mint(to, amount);

        payable(creatorAddress).transfer(msg.value / 10);
    }
}
```

This code sends 10% of every payment to the `creatorAddress`.

Comment: Thank You for answer. How to specify for example 0.01 eth instead 10% and also how to limit the supply for minting ? Thank You!